# Array.map JSON time table to grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, next.js, css-grid, array.prototype.map

I use Next.js 10 to build like a timetable or a schedule
I want something like this (from json)

| bushaltestelle | zeit 1 | zeit 2 | zeit 3 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| props[0].bushaltestelle | props[0].zeiten[0] | props[0].zeiten[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNg7.png) | props[0].zeiten[2] | ... |
| props[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNg7.png).bushaltestelle | props[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNg7.png).zeiten[0] | props[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNg7.png).zeiten[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNg7.png) | props[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNg7.png).zeiten[2] | ... |
| props[2].bushaltestelle | props[2].zeiten[0] | props[2].zeiten[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNg7.png) | props[2].zeiten[2] | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

json:

```json
[
   {
      "bushaltestelle":"Bad Königshofen ZOB",
      "zeiten":[
         "05:55",
         "06:35",
         "06:35",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "07:15",
         "07:15",
         "08:15",
         "09:15",
         "10:15",
         "11:15",
         "12:15",
         "12:15",
         "NULL",
         "13:10",
         "13:15",
         "NULL",
         "14:15",
         "15:30",
         "15:15",
         "16:15",
         "16:15",
         "17:15",
         "17:15",
         "18:15"
      ]
   },
   {
      "bushaltestelle":"Bad Königshofen Schulzentrum",
      "zeiten":[
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "12:17",
         "NULL",
         "13:10",
         "13:17",
         "NULL",
         "13:30",
         "NULL",
         "15:32",
         "NULL",
         "16:17",
         "NULL",
         "17:17",
         "NULL",
         "NULL"
      ]
   },
   {
      "bushaltestelle":"Großeibstadt",
      "zeiten":[
         "06:00",
         "06:40",
         "06:40",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "NULL",
         "07:20",
         "07:20",
         "08:20",
         "09:20",
         "10:20",
         "11:20",
         "12:20",
         "12:20",
         "13:15",
         "NULL",
         "13:20",
         "NULL",
         "14:20",
         "15:35",
         "15:20",
         "16:20",
         "16:20",
         "17:20",
         "17:20",
         "18:20"
      ]
   }
]
```

I can generate to "bushaltestelle" row with

```
{props.map(props => <div className={styles.grid_left}>{props.bushaltestelle}</div>)}
```

But I dont know how to generate the "zeiten"

For better understanding: Bushaltestellen => bus stops; zeiten => times
So I have in the first column all bus stops in the direction the bus drives, and then I have the times when the bus arrives at the bus stop.

If I have a bad json design, then I can change it. But the "bushaltestellen" and the "zeiten" must be able to be any lenght. so it should work whether i have 1 or 2 million

Edit (thanks to @yochanan sheinberger):

```
{props.map(prop => 
  <grid className={styles.grid_container}>
    <div className={styles.grid_left}>{prop.bushaltestelle}</div>
    {prop.zeiten.map(zeit => <div className={styles.grid_right}>{zeit}</div>)}
  </grid>
)}
```

my css:

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(24, 1fr);
  gap: 0px 0px;
}

.grid_left {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.grid_right {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

My Custom Solution to answer:

```
<table className={styles.tg}>
  {props.map(prop =>
    <tr>
      <th className={styles.tg_0pky}>{prop.bushaltestelle}</th>
      {prop.zeiten.map(zeit => zeit === "NULL" ? <th className={styles.tg_0pky}></th> : <th className={styles.tg_0pky}>{zeit}</th>)}
    </tr>
  )}
</table>
```

css:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg_0pky {
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

This will look like this:
[image: preview]

Comment: In the second map `zeit` refers to the current element which is a string. So `zeit[0]` will give you the first character of it. Why do you expect it to be the full string?

Comment: @yochanansheinberger edited. bit of misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you will have to make adjustments, but this is the idea.

```
{props.map(prop => {
 <div>
  <div className={styles.grid_left}>{prop.bushaltestelle}</div>
  {prop.zeiten.map(zeit => <div>{zeit}</div>)}
 </div>
)}
```

or with table element:

```
<table>
  {props.map((prop, i) => 
    <>
      {i === 0 && <tr><th></th>{prop.zeiten.map((z, i) => <th>{"zeit" + i}</th>)}</tr>}
      <tr>
        <th >{prop.bushaltestelle}</th>
        {prop.zeiten.map(zeit => <td>{zeit !== "NULL" ? zeit : "-"}</td>)}
      </tr>
    </>
  )}
</table>
```

Comment: There is a typo in first line: last `{` shouldn't be there. I test the code later

Comment: But how do i but each element into a nice grid, and not just below eachother

Comment: Can't you use table elements?

Comment: i already wrote it so i posted it. maybe you will find it helpful